# SSRS Reports - Hiding a Tablix doesn't shrink the space and move content after it up

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix with another tablix beneath it with 0 space between the bottom of the first tablix and the top of the second. When I change the Hidden property of the first tablix to true, it hides the tablix with empty space but doesn't move the second tablix up.

Is is possible to hide the first tablix and move the second tablix up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, just figured it out. Have to add both tablixes to the same rectangle. Then hiding the first tablix moves the second one up.